# Quick successful exit from C++ with lots of objects allocated

Tags: c++, heap-memory, destructor, exit, abort

I'm looking for a way to quickly exit a C++ that has allocated a lot of structures in memory using C++ classes.  The program finishes correctly, but after the final "return" in the program, all of the auto-destructors kick in.  The problem is the program has allocated about 15GB of memory through lots of C++ class structures, and this auto-destruct process takes about 1 more hour itself to complete as it walks through all of the structures - even though I don't care about the results.  The program only took 1 hour to complete the task up to this point.  I would like to just return to the OS and let it do its normal wholesale process allocation deletion - which is very quick.  I've been doing this by manually killing the process during the cleanup stage - but am looking for a better programic solution.

I would like to return a success to the OS, but don't care to keep any of the memory content.  The program does perform a lot of dynamic allocation/deallocation during the normal processing, so it's not just simple heap management.

Any opinions?

Comment: It just can not take one hour if you are not doing anything in destructor. There must be something which is blocking it. Have you tried profiling it?

Answer (score 4):

In Standard C++ you only have abort(), but that has the process return failure to the OS.

On many platforms (Unix, MS Windows) you can use _exit() to exit the program without running cleanup and destructors.

Comment: _exit() says nothing about destructors since it is POSIX function (that tell nothing about C++). Currently it does not call any destructors on platform i have, but it is not guaranteed by documentation.

Comment: That is why I said that this works on specific platforms. But as discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/q/4769229/585729 that should be the case on any platform where it exists.

Answer (score 3):

C++0x [std::quick_exit](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/utility/program/quick_exit) is what you are looking for if your compiler already supports it (g++-4.4.5 does).

Answer (score 1):

If the 15 GB of memory is being allocated to a reasonably small number of classes, you could override operator delete for those classes. Just pass the call to the standard delete, but set up a global flag that, if set, will make the call to delete a no-op. Or, if the logic of your program is such that these objects are not deleted in the normal course of building your data structures, you could simply ignore delete in all cases for these classes.

Answer (score 1):

As Naveen says, this can't be a matter of memory deallocation. I've written neural network simulations with evolutionary algorithms that where allocating and freed lots of memory in small and large chunks and this was never a major issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a C99 compiler, you can use the [`_Exit`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/_exit) function to end immediately without having global object destructors or any functions registered with `atexit` to be called; whether or not unwritten buffered file data is flushed, open streams are closed, or temporary files are removed is implementation-defined (C99 §7.20.4.4).

If you're on Windows, you can also use [`ExitProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682658%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to achieve the same effect.

But, as others have said, your destructors should really not be taking an hour to run unless you're doing a fair amount of I/O (writing log files, etc.).  I strongly, strongly recommend you profile your program to see where the time is spent.

Answer (score 1):

The possible strategies depend on the number of objects that are directly visible in `main` through which you access the 15GB of data and if these are local to main or statically allocated.

If *all* access to the 15GB of data is through local objects in `main`, then you can simply replace the `return 0;` at the end of `main` with `exit(0);`.
`exit` will terminate your application and trigger cleanup of statically allocated variables, but **not** of local variables.

If the data is accessed through a handful of statically allocated variables, you could turn them into pointers (or references) to dynamically allocated memory and deliberately leak that.