# how to abort a c++ program and exit with status 0?

Tags: c++, abort

I want to kill my c++ program and terminate immediately without activating destructors of any kind,  especially static and global variables, but I want to exit with status 0 - `abort()` will not work for me.

Does anyone have a solution?
Thanks

Comment: Why does `abort()` not work for you if I may ask?

Comment: Why do you not want to activate destructors?

Comment: "`The function generates the SIGABRT signal, which by default causes the program to terminate returning an unsuccessful termination error code to the host environment."

Comment: If nothing gets cleaned up then why would you want to exit with a code of 0?

Comment: @Joe: Most of the stuff gets cleaned up. By OS. You don't know what his application is doing. There is a reason why `_exit` system call is there :)

Comment: its a program that runs under an environment of python scripts, its a long story

Comment: @VladLazarenko I am quite familiar with `exit(0)` but that performs proper clean up which the OP does not want. `abort` terminates the program without calling any destructors and exits with an unsuccessful termination code as it should.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4769229/594137) is probably worth your time if you haven't already read it.

Comment: As an intermediate, there's [`std::quick_exit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/quick_exit).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe `_exit(0);` is what you're looking for?

Here is the [man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/exit.2.html) to read up about it.

Comment: that would activate the destructors wouldn't it?

Comment: In C++11, this is standardised as either `std::_Exit` (inherited from C99) or `std::quick_exit`.

Answer (score 6):

From C++11 n3290 - § 18.5:

```
[[noreturn]] void _Exit(int status) noexcept;
```

> The program is terminated without executing destructors for objects of automatic, thread, or
>   static storage duration and without calling functions passed to atexit()

This is actually defined in C99 though so in practice works on a large number of pre-C++11 implementations.

Use:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

struct test {
  ~test() {
    std::cout << "Goodbye world" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  test t;
  _Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I think this would be more helpful if you were to clarify which versions of C++ this would and wouldn't work in.

Comment: @Styne666: n3290 means C++11. But the function is part of C99. And it would likely work even before that.

Answer (score 1):

How about [`_Exit(0)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/_exit.html) from `stdlib.h`. (Demo: http://ideone.com/ecCgC)

Comment: That will still call destructors of global and static objects.

Comment: @bitmask: No it does not. Check N3290 §18.5/3.

Comment: @bitmask: Not in C++11 it won't. In C++03, its not specified, but probably still won't.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, KennyTM: I'm sorry, that comment was supposed to go on the `exit(0)` proposal. Either this is a bug in the SO-engine or I clicked the wrong link.