# What's the difference between _Exit() and _exit()?

Tags: c++

In answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8804643/594137), some people have said to use [_Exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8804701/594137) and others have said to use [_exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8804676/594137).  Could someone explain the difference (if any) between the two, and the origins of both?

Comment: Erm, it's all pretty much right there in the answers to that question including the standards that define them. In fact, the man page you link to tells you *exactly* where each came from ... what out of those answers do you need clarification on?

Comment: The origins, and therefore why to chose one over the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right from the man page [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/exit.2.html):

> The function _Exit() is equivalent to _exit().

Although in C++11, it is standardized as either std::_Exit or std::quick_exit. According to [Mike Seymour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204847/mike-seymour) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804643/how-to-abort-a-c-program-and-exit-with-status-0/8804676#8804676).

Comment: On Linux they are equivalent. On OS X (BSD), however, `The _Exit() function terminates without calling the functions registered with the atexit(3) function, and may or may not perform the other actions listed` that `exit()` (without underscore) does which are flushing open output streams, closing open streams and unlinking temporary files created using `tmpfile(3)`. After this both `exit()` and `_Exit()` calls `_exit()` to terminate the process.

Answer (score 5):

`_Exit(2)` is from C99. `_exit(2)` is from POSIX. At least, according to the manpage I have installed here.

They are entirely equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

`_exit()` and `_Exit()` are absolutely identical. To understand the differences between `exit()` and `_exit()`, you would need to know about the functions `on_exit(3)` and `atexit(3)`. These functions are used to register functions that are called automatically when the process exits normally, that is, via a return from `main()`, or via a call to `exit()`. `on_exit()` and `atexit()` differ only in that they allow functions to be registered with different signatures (think of these registered functions as destructors (as in object-oriented programming) for the processes).

`exit()`, upon being called attempts to execute all the functions registered using `atexit()` or `onexit()`. Upon executing them, it calls `_exit()`. `_exit()` does the normal process termination stuff - closing file-descriptors, releasing memory, re-parenting orphaned children to init, et cetera. Think of `_exit()` as the bare-bones system call used by a process to terminate itself.

Since a whole lot of applications do not use `atexit()` or `on_exit()`, for these, `_exit()`, `_Exit()`, and `exit()` behave identically.