# Difference between _exit and return

Tags: c, fork, exit

Consider the following piece of code

```
    int     glob = 6;       /* external variable in initialized data */

    int
    main(void)
    {
        int     var;        /* automatic variable on the stack */
        pid_t   pid;

        var = 88;
        printf("before vfork\n");   /* we don't flush stdio */

        if ( (pid = vfork()) < 0)
            err_sys("vfork error");
        else if (pid == 0) {        /* child */
            glob++;                 /* modify parent's variables */
            var++;
            _exit(0);               /* child terminates */
        }

        /* parent */
        printf("pid = %d, glob = %d, var = %d\n", getpid(), glob, var);
        exit(0);
    }
```

This is an example explaing how to use the vfork syscall.
    If, instead of using _exit i use return, i get different output values. Is not return equivalent to call _exit? Why not?

Comment: "except that **the behavior is undefined** if the process created by `vfork()` either modifies any data other than a variable of type  `pid_t`  used  to store  the  return  value from `vfork()`" "**The child must not return from the current function or call `exit(3)`**, but may call `_exit(2)`" And no, `return` isn't equivalent to `_exit()`, kind of equivalent to `exit()`.

Comment: it is already discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769229/how-will-exit-behave-in-a-c-program)!

Comment: Ok. And it's also wrong because the two processes share the stack?